# Safari doesn't play HEVC 4k/UHD HLS stream

Tags: safari, video-streaming, hevc

As part of testing and debugging, I'm trying to play a 4k HLS stream encoded in HEVC in Safari on a mid-2015 MacBook Pro with High Sierra 10.13.6.

But Safari refuses to select the 4k quality, it only plays 1080p and lower. I encoded a stream with only one quality in 4k, and then Safari says "unsupported plugin".

The streams are encoded with a professional grade commercial product and they play in ffplay. The codec string in the manifest is hvc1.1.6.L150.B0 and the bitrate is around 9 Mbit/s, which I believe falls within Apple's constraints.

Apple is very obtuse in providing information. Will Safari NEVER play a HEVC 4k stream on my laptop? Is there some setup where I definitely should be able to play this stream at 4k, such as casting to an AppleTv4k or plugging in a 4k capable TV and running Safari fullscreen? What exactly are the conditions here?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, your videos will play at full 4K using Chrome or Firefox on the same Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the streaming packager set the wrong profile in the hvcc atom. Once this was patched, casting 4k to AppleTV started working.